# Как продолжить выполнять функцию и цикл одновременно?

Tags: python, функции, while

Мне нужно чтобы продолжилось выполнение `main()` а также началось выполнение `timer()`

```
def timer():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Текст цикла")



def main():
    timer()
    
    print("Текст функции")
```

Comment: Запускаете отдельный поток для функции `timer`, читать про потоки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких функций в `python` используется модуль `threading`. Вот пример реализации вашей задачи с использованием данного модуля:

```
import threading
import time

def timer():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Текст цикла")



def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = timer)
    t1.start()
    print("Текст функции")

main()
```

В строке `t1 = threading.Thread(target = timer)` мы создаем поток и в параметр `target` указываем функцию, которую он будет выполнять.

В строке `t1.start()` мы запускам поток

Comment: Можно ли как-то закрыть Thread (ex. `file.close()`), Или его не нужно закрывать?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, что при каком-то действии поток останавливается, то да. Нужно лишь создать глобальную переменную со значением `True`, например `x = True` и в функции `timer` создать цикл не `while True:` , а `while x:` и когда при выполнении каких-либо действий поток нужно остановить, просто прописываете `x = False`

Comment: Ну в целом да, В итоге большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Сначала надо открыть учебник по Python и прочитать что нибудь про  Потоки и процессы в Python. Это идеальный путь. Путь по проще - ограничиться какой-нибудь информацией из интернет, ну например:

```
https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-22-concurrency-part-1/
https://gb.ru/posts/python_threading_part1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ad5fHlFHbOg
```